# How do I fix my broken tab completion?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something went terribly wrong with my ROS Kinetic.
I think it went wrong after trying to solve vtk warnings described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369369/compiling-pcl-1-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-errors-in-cmake-generated-makefile?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (a compiling warning from the Point Cloud Library that I wanted to be gone).
I installed `python-vtk` (a terrible decision, **don't do it if you're using `ros-pcl`**) which removed conflicting packages or something, because some other packages weren't working anymore.
To solve that I removed python-vtk again and reinstalled all the broken packages for my project with `rosdep install <my_package>`. To my surprise, a lot of packages were "not installed" anymore. My project worked again, but tab completion was broken somehow.

The way tab completion behaves now is that the first tab completion works fine, like tabbing `rosd` shows me `rosdep`, `rosdep-source`, etc... But with tabbing for the the next argument, it just shows me the contents of the current folder. I've sourced the setup.bash and all the environment variables seem fine:

> ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
> ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
> ROS_VERSION=1
> ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
> ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros

Then I thought maybe something is wrong with ROS too, not only the packages. So first I tried installing ROS Kinetic like described on the tutorial page, but without removing my old ROS first. To my surprise it actually installed, not saying that it already is installed? So my ROS Kinetic was working without my Ubuntu (16.04 64-bit, kernel 4.4.0-127-generic) knowing that it was installed. *What is going here???* Something happened that made my system think that nothing from ROS is installed anymore, but it still works. Also this installation did solve tab completion for `roslaunch`, but it did not for `rosdep` (e.g. `rosdep install`, it doesn't tab complete `install`). (This also raises the question if I can even remove ROS things if the system thinks it's not installed? Not tested yet though.)

So to sum it up, everything works fine except for certain tab completions and my system thinks some ROS components are not installed even though they are.
My next try to solve this is removing everything from ROS first and then reinstalling everything again.
But I'd like to delay this step first, since I can just work with ROS for now. If anyone here doesn't know any other solution I will proceed with reinstalling everything from ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291867/how-do-i-fix-my-broken-tab-completion?/) by [DmasterD](https://answers.ros.org/users/35370/dmasterd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-05-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First off, not *all* ROS packages have great tab autocomplete support. For example `rosrun`, `roslaunch`, `rospack`, and `rosmsg` all have good support while tools like `rosdep` and `rosinstall` do not. So the fact that your `rosdep` tab autocomplete is not working is not actually a problem.

Likely the original issue that you faced was that some package you installed with `apt-get` conflicted with some subset of ROS packages. You didn't read the command line output when installing the conflicting package, and you gave the okay to uninstall the conflicting packages. The `ros-kinetic-desktop-full` package is really just a metapackage that depends on a bundled set of ROS packages. If you uninstall any of these dependencies, then the desktop-full package is also automatically removed. However, other dependencies of desktop-full are not automatically removed (this is what `apt-get autoremove` is for). Thus, this could explain how you ended up with a partially-installed ROS Kinetic distribution. This would also explain why running `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full` would actually end up installing a bunch of packages (but perhaps not all of the dependent packages if you already had some of them installed). Note that if you really want to get to the bottom of what happened `/var/log/apt` contains a `history.log` and many older `history.log.XX.gz` files. These files include all `apt-get` commands that were run and summaries of which packages were modified as a result. Looking through these files could tell you exactly what originally conflicted, what ROS packages were uninstalled, and show how installing desktop full re-installed the removed packages.

If you were able to run `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full` with no issues, then I'd say your ROS system is installed correctly.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DmasterD](https://answers.ros.org/users/35370/dmasterd/) on 2018-05-22**:
Thank you for the big explanation. I think I understand now what happened. Although I did run `apt autoremove`, and ROS still worked (except for the tab completion). Anyways, I installed `ros-kinetic-desktop-full` again and so far it's all working like it should. :) Thanks for your time.

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-01-19**:
Makes perfect sense. I had the same issue with ROS noetic. It works now